# Getting incorrect format error while adding a post

Tags: android, ios, getstream-io

I m using the `getStream` example code and trying to add an activity but It's giving the error:

> ❌ save 57 unexpectedError(Optional(GetStream.ClientError.jsonDecode("The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", Optional(Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "actor", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))), 192 bytes)))

but activity are getting saved.
Why this is happening and how to fix this.

This is the [GitHub](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-swift) link

Response is :

```
some : "{\"actor\":\"SU:7472280e-512c-44c9-a6ad-404da33ee076\",\"duration\":\"8.54ms\",\"foreign_id\":\"\",\"id\":\"a72e87a3-82ad-11e9-8bf3-0a9265761cda\",\"object\":\"As\",\"origin\":null,\"target\":\"\",\"time\":\"2019-05-30T07:36:35.730832\",\"verb\":\"post\"}\n"
```

Comment: Aashish, I'd suggest to create an issue on their github

Comment: Aashish, could you show the code with request?
I think the problem is that response is not enriched, but the request is expecting to get for an actor a user object.